# Custom view isn't drawn in Android

Tags: java, android, canvas, kotlin

I'm implementing custom button for my android application where must be only none-filled circle. I'm relatively new in this side of Android developing so I got trouble about it.

There's custom attributes:

```
<resources>
<declare-styleable name="CircleButton">
    <attr name="stroke_width" format="dimension"/>
</declare-styleable>
```

Code of class:

```
class CircleButton (context: Context,
                attrs: AttributeSet) : View(context, attrs) {

val paint: Paint = Paint()

init {
    var a = context.theme.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.CircleButton, 0, 0)
    paint.color = Color.RED
    try {
        paint.strokeWidth = a.getDimension(R.styleable.CircleButton_stroke_width, 3f)
    } finally {
        a.recycle()
    }
}

var centerX = x + width / 2
var centerY = y + height / 2
var radius = width / 2


override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas) {
   super.onDraw(canvas)
   canvas.drawCircle(centerX.toFloat(), centerY.toFloat(), radius.toFloat(), paint)
}

override fun onMeasure(w : Int, h : Int) {
    setMeasuredDimension(w, w)
}
```

It is Kotlin, but I guess it's all clear with it. But anyway I can provide Java-code, if needed.

There's layout XML:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:paddingLeft="0dp"
    android:paddingRight="0dp"
    android:paddingTop="0dp"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

<com.prox1mity.myapplication.CircleButton
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    custom:stroke_width="3dp"
/>
```

When I run application, I see only white screen, which means that onDraw method doesn't work properly. But if I'm changing drawing of circle to just filling the canvas with color via `canvas.drawColor()` it's all right, the view is fully filled. That leads me to thought that something wrong with my `Paint` class or my wrong apprehension of coordinate system. How to draw the circle with center in center of View properly?

Comment: Hmm, I'm not familiar with Kotlin, but if I'm following the code correctly, you wanna drop the `x` from the `centerX` calculation, and the `y` from `centerY`. That is, `var centerX = width / 2`, `var centerY = height / 2`.

Comment: Well, it doesn't work.

Comment: Oh, right. You don't wanna do those calculations there. There, the `View` will have 0 dimensions. Move those calculations into its `onSizeChanged()` method. Or even into `onDraw()`, if you just wanna do a quick test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var centerX = x + width / 2
var centerY = y + height / 2
var radius = width / 2
```

This code will be evaluated at the initialization of the instance. And at this moment, `width` = 0 and `height` = 0. Because the view it's not already measured.

You can add a `Log.d(...)` or a breakpoint in `onDraw` and you will see that `radius` = 0.

For a rapid test, you can change `onDraw` to:

```
override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas) {
   super.onDraw(canvas)

   val centerX = width / 2
   val centerY = height / 2
   val radius = width / 2
   canvas.drawCircle(centerX.toFloat(), centerY.toFloat(), radius.toFloat(), paint)
}
```

Maybe you can optimize this code. Doing allocations in `onDraw` is not a very good idea. You can find explanation [here](https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/optimizing-view.html).